# How does the second CASE statement affect performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, case-when

I want to better understand what happens behind the scenes in the following query:

```
SELECT s.Question_Id, s.Question,
CASE WHEN 
    ( SUM(CASE WHEN sr.Answer = 1 THEN 1 WHEN sr.Answer = 0 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END)
    ) IS NULL THEN 'N/A' 
    ELSE CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN sr.Answer = 1 THEN 1 WHEN sr.Answer = 0 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END) AS VARCHAR) END           
    AS Answered_Yes
FROM SurveyResult sr
INNER JOIN Survey s
ON sr.Question_Id = s.Question_Id
GROUP BY s.Question_Id, s.Question
```

*Just to better understand the query, it returns a surveys results with the sum of 'Yes' answers.*

Note: I am doing the `CAST` because the `CASE` statement can only return a single data type and instead of returning NULL, I want to return N/A.
So my question is does this line (in the `ELSE`):

```
CASE WHEN sr.Answer = 1 THEN 1 WHEN sr.Answer = 0 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END
```

actually run twice ? According to the execution plan it does have an additional compute scalar operation, but does it use cache since it's just done that exact same check in the first check of the `WHEN` statement?

Hope my questions are clear, as I have had this scenario before and wanted to know the performance implications of the query.

Comment: Not quite.  This line is: `SUM(CASE WHEN sr.Answer = 1 THEN 1 WHEN sr.Answer = 0 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END)`.  I don't think SQL Server is smart enough to optimize that away, although I might be wrong.

Comment: Note casting to varchar without length specified (will be varchar(1))

Answer (score 2):

Am not sure about the additional scalar operator in execution plan but your query can be simplified like this

```
SELECT s.Question_Id,
       s.Question,
       Isnull(cast(Sum(CASE sr.Answer
                       WHEN  1 THEN 1
                       WHEN  0 THEN 0
                    ELSE NULL
                  END) as varchar(100)), 'N/A') AS Answered_Yes
FROM   SurveyResult sr
       INNER JOIN Survey s
               ON sr.Question_Id = s.Question_Id
GROUP  BY s.Question_Id,
          s.Question
```

But I guess execution plan will still be the same.

Comment: +1 Brilliant, Thanks, that's a lot easier and avoid's the duplicate CASE statement, just still curios how it handles that duplicate... Appreciate the help!

Comment: @EaziLuizi - What do you meant by duplicates? can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: No not the data, if you see my query I perform that CASE...WHEN twice, so yours solves that problem, interestingly though it's execution plan is identical. But I will rather use yours, MUCH more readable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you never need to say, "ELSE NULL" in a CASE statement; the default ELSE behavior is to return a NULL value. Next, If SurveyResult.Answer can only be 1 or 0 then your query can be further simplified like this:

```
SELECT s.Question_Id,
       s.Question,
       Isnull(cast(Sum(sr.answer) as varchar(100)), 'N/A') AS Answered_Yes
FROM   SurveyResult sr
INNER JOIN Survey s
  ON sr.Question_Id = s.Question_Id
GROUP  BY s.Question_Id, s.Question
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, That's why I love asking questions, learn new things like the default ELSE behaviour returns NULL.